# Select for Update using limit in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, select, for-loop

I need to distribute the processing on records to different machines.

On each of these machines(nodes), I run the following query every minutes:

```
select * 
from RECORDS_TO_PROCESS
limit MAX_PER_MACHINE_RUN
for update
```

Hypothetically, assume that I have 1000 records to process, 10 machines(nodes) and each machine wants to process 100 records(max) in a minute.

```
R1
R2
R3
...
R101
R102
R103
...
R201
R202
R203
...
```

All I want is for Records (R1-100) to get to query made from Node1, Records (R101-R200) to be returned from query made from Node2 etc.

Will this work? Do we think that this would be able to spread load?

Assume that the transaction isolation level is the default one (Read Committed)

Answer (score 6):

That won't work because the first query to lock a row for update will block all subsequent queries attempting to lock that same row, until the first one commits.  Version 9.5 will introduce `SKIP LOCKED` so that they will not block each other, but rather all get different rows.

Until 9.5 is out, you could use `pg_try_advisory_lock` in the WHERE clause to emulate the `SKIP LOCKED` feature.  You would have to arrange for each row to have a unique(ish) identifier to feed to `pg_try_advisory_lock`.

But I think that this is a mistaken design anyway.  You almost always want to first claim a row by writing some identifier (like node + pid) into a column and committing it, and then do a second transaction to mark it as done once it is done.

And if you are limiting it to 100 per minute, I don't see a reason to try to select 100 at a time.  Just do one at a time, once every half second.  the overhead should be tolerable, unless your database has a very high ping time.

Comment: > "first query to lock a row for update will block all subsequent queries " I am sorry that I dont understand this. Are we saying that if two nodes (N1 and N2) each make the query to get 100 rows (first N1 and then N2), then query for N2 will have to wait to return its 100 records till N1 finishes processing its 100 records (that it fetched).

Comment: If the first transaction is run in a transaction which remains upon during the processing, yes, the 2nd one blocks.  And if the first transaction is run outside of any transaction, then the "FOR UPDATE" doesn't do anything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SKIP LOCKED is quite cool. I suggest upgrading!

I'm curious about the other way (claiming the row first through an update/commit). Is it really better than just a FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED? The only advantage I see is portability to other RDBMS.

Comment: For recent discussion of the perils of leaving transactions open while processing the items, see https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/33bae6e3-1c5a-77f0-ee99-408fbf0fbb83%40gusw.net.  The obsolete row can't be cleaned up until the oldest open transaction closes.  Processes wanting a new row have to dig through the remnants of both the locked rows and the old rows each time, which quickly gets slow.